# How to do connectionless UDP broadcast using Wi-Fi?

Tags: ad-hoc-networks, wifi-direct

I'm hoping to broadcast UDP packets using the Wi-Fi antenna to everyone else (running the same application) in range. I'd like to do this without having to establish a connection. Is this possible?

I'm able to establish a P2P Wi-Fi connection and then send a multicast message, but that's not quite what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, but you must learn [IEE802.11 Datagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11#Layer_2_.E2.80.93_Datagrams) very well. There are two ways, the first provides two-way data exchange, the second only broadcasts to receivers:

1. use the [beacon frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beacon_frame) and Probe request/response frame to send data from AP to clients without connection

   - [Broadcasting Information in Variably Dense Environment Using Connectionless Data Exchange (CoLDE)](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=qzygBQAAQBAJ)
2. use the length field in the data frame to broadcast only. You should develop a communication protocol with the encoded length. The receiver should:

   - enter [Promiscuous Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode)
   - switch channels
   - Provide a 100ms timer interrupt at least.

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't how Wi-Fi works. You have to join the same Wi-Fi network first before sending any kind of IP datagrams.